# How can I use a filter to show everything except cells containing specific words?

Tags: google-sheets, google-calendar

I'm importing a Google Calendar (ics link in A2 that I'm importing with an `IMPORTDATA` function) and it has system dates related to 1970 that I obviously want to filter.

How can I specify to show me everything EXCEPT cells containing `DTSTART:1970*`

`=FILTER(index(IMPORTDATA(A2),,1), index(IMPORTDATA(A2),,1)<>"DTSTART:19700308T020000", index(IMPORTDATA(A2),,1)<>"DTSTART:19700405T030000", index(IMPORTDATA(A2),,1)<>"DTSTART:19701004T020000", index(IMPORTDATA(A2),,1)<>"DTSTART:19701101T020000")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`=query( importdata(A2), "select Col1 where not Col1 contains 'DTSTART:1970' ", 0 )`

See the [query language help page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Language_Syntax).

Comment: Fantastic, it works!

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)